# Angular2 Reactive form.reset() not clearing custom component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

In Angular2RC5 my application, I have an SSN input whose job is to add dashes as the user types in their SSN (ex 123-34-3434).  I'm using this as part of a "reactive form" (the ones that aren't template forms...).  My template looks like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <p class="lead">Please enter your <span *ngIf="context==='fr-secondary'">Spouse's </span> Last Name, SSN, Tax Year, and Quarter</p>
    //other inputs
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2" for="inputSSN">SSN</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ssn-input formControlName="ssn"></ssn-input>
        <!--<span class="help-block error" *ngIf="form.controls['ssn'].errors && form.controls['ssn'].errors['required']">required</span>
        <span class="help-block error" *ngIf="form.controls['ssn'].errors && form.controls['ssn'].errors['patternError']">Invalid SSN</span>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next</button>
</form>
```

Whenever they click submit, we save the data, and then if they've indicated that they're married, we want to reset the form and collect the data for their spouse.

So when I do `this.form.reset()`, all of the inputs except the SSN input (the custom one) reset, and the value of the SSN on the backend of the form resets, but the previous value is still visible to the user (which means if they click submit, it'll submit as an empty string, even if they can see one).

I've also tried doing `this.form.controls['ssn'].setValue('')` and it does the same thing.  Changes the value on the form, but the value is still showing on the page.

Here's the whole SSN component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';


export function createSSNPatternValidator() {
  return (c: FormControl) => {
    let pattern = /\d{9}/;
    let err = {
      patternError: {
        pattern: /\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}/
      }
    };
  return (c.value && !c.value.match(pattern) && c.value.length > 0) ? err : null;
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ssn-input',
  template: `
    <input type="text" (input)="updateValue($event)" class="form-control" />
  `,
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => SSNInputComponent), multi: true },
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => SSNInputComponent), multi: true }
  ]
})
export class SSNInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {

  value: string = '';
  propagateChange: any = () => {};
  validateFn: any = () => {};


  ngOnInit() {
    this.validateFn = createSSNPatternValidator();
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    if (value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}

  updateValue(event) {
    let newValue = event.target.value;
    newValue = newValue.replace(/\D/g, '').substr(0, 9);
    this.value = newValue;
    newValue =
      newValue.substr(0, 3) + ((newValue.length >= 4) ? ('-' + newValue.substr(3, 2) + ((newValue.length >= 6) ? '-' + newValue.substr(5, 4) : '')) : '');
    event.target.value = newValue;
    this.propagateChange(this.value);
  }


  validate(c: FormControl) {
    return this.validateFn(c);
  }
}
```

EDIT:  [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0iVxcXSV5ljm5o7c86DE?p=preview)

Comment: After some discussion in the angular2 gitter, we've decided that unless we're missing something, it might be a bug within angular itself.  as such, I filed a bug on github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11073

Comment: See also the explanation in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11073 (just for cross-reference)

Comment: I see kara's explanation now, but the example she provided doesn't quite work for me.  "Property 'nativeElement' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement"

Comment: Then it is already the `nativeElement`. Just remove `.nativeElement` there

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the value to the input if it is updated using `writeValue`.

This code

```
  writeValue(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ArHS75AZUhRrTnFGO0TN?p=preview)

Comment: Good catch, although that's not the issue.  Here's a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/0iVxcXSV5ljm5o7c86DE?p=preview

I removed that `if statement` but it's still not working

Comment: I believe the issue might be that `form.reset()` doesn't work for custom ValueAccessors?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `if(value)` from `writValue()`?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm saying I did

Comment: The Plunker in my answer is similar to what was explained in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11073

Comment: Remove the `if (value)` condition, and the form `reset()` call will work as expected when using custom Value Accessors. I've edited this answer accordingly.